# Error Xamarin Forms Previewer - Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After installing Visual Studio 2017 Community I got the following error. Is someone going through this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, try to reopen the xaml file as this is a common error with Xamarin Forms previewer (source: my short experience). Your settings seem ok, so let it rerender it again. If that doesn't help try to reinstall previewer from official Xamarin website or try with very simple .xaml file.

Unfortunately, the previewer still doesn't work properly and no one recommends using it. I gave up for now.

Comment: Hi Dominiki,
I've tried all these procedures, with VS2015 working.